# Can one identify a certain family of degree-$2 j$ polynomials ($j=1,2,\ldots$)

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, gamma-function

I presently have computations for $j=1,\ldots,37$ of a family of $2 j$-degree polynomials.
From them, it appears that the leading (highest power) coefficients are given (in descending order) by the rules:
\begin{equation}
d_1=\frac{\left(\frac{17}{2}\right)^n}{\Gamma (n+1)},
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
d_2=\frac{2^{-n-2} 17^{n-2} (1109-497 n)}{3 \Gamma (n)},
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
d_3=\frac{2^{-n-5} 17^{n-4} (n (n (247009 n-1370262)+3942323)-11308734)}{9 \Gamma (n)}.
\end{equation}
Also, $d_4$ is the product of 
\begin{equation}
-\frac{2^{-n-7} 17^{n-6} (n-1) n}{405 \Gamma (n+1)}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
613817365 n^4-5492491130 n^3+30016283027 n^2-173872269670 n+542508998592.
\end{equation}

Further, $d_5$ is the product of 
\begin{equation}
\frac{2^{-n-11} 17^{n-8} (n-1) n}{1215 \Gamma (n+1)}
\end{equation} 
and 
\begin{equation}
305067230405 n^6-4403156498055 n^5+38051293414691 n^4
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
-325978342903557
   n^3+2137571940201488 n^2-8722204904328012 n+13657232612174832.
\end{equation}
Continuing, $d_6$ is the product of 
\begin{equation}
-\frac{2^{-n-13} 17^{n-10} (n-2) (n-1) n}{25515 \Gamma (n+1)}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
212265778915799 n^7-4033760477145378 n^6+46257531538470350 n^5-526319720165886192
   n^4
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
+5002806671861237555 n^3-35895786322816308558 n^2+169446873953910154824
   n-385892347895176978944,
\end{equation}
while $d_7$ is the product of 
\begin{equation}
\frac{2^{-n-16} 17^{n-12} (n-2) (n-1) n}{1148175 \Gamma (n+1)}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
527480460605760515 n^9-14061542253335879085 n^8+216128338841103270330
   n^7-3070915881213672409050 n^6
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
+39074939804872696010811 n^5-414647891239558549971645
   n^4+3466800379462987766973880 n^3
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
-20874814527662001270399420
   n^2+78054176824402526959936464 n-118165465673929410155118720.
\end{equation}

I, of course, would hope to eventually fully characterize the family, and may be able to deduce (using, as above, the Mathematica FindSequenceFunction command) one or two more such coefficients. I can test possible $d_8,\ldots$ candidates against the $j=1,\ldots,37$ computations. I have  also examined the ratios $r_i=\frac{d_{i+1}}{d_i}$, with the results
\begin{equation}
{r_1,r_2}= \left\{\frac{(1109-497 n) n}{3468},\frac{n ((1370262-247009 n) n-3942323)+11308734}{6936
   (497 n-1109)}\right\}.
\end{equation}
Actually, the $j$-th $2 j$-degree polynomial, formulas for the leading coefficients of which I  have just presented, yields the rule for the coefficient $c_{j+1}$ of the $(4 n-2)$-degree polynomials $p_{n}(k)$ (in monic form [$c_1=1$]--the original leading coefficient having been $\frac{2^{8 n+1}}{(2 n-1)!}$) discussed in App. A of https://www.hindawi.com/journals/amp/2015/621353/, "Formulas for Rational-Valued Separability Probabilities of Random Induced Generalized Two-Qubit States", by 
Paul B. Slater and Charles F. Dunkl. (The variable $\alpha$ there has been changed to $n$ here. A Mathematica file containing these five expressions is available upon request [slater@kitp.ucsb.edu].) The sequence of (negative) integer exponents of 2--that is, 0, 2, 5, 7, 11, 13, 16--is found in the OEIS https://oeis.org/search?q=0%2C2%2C5%2C7%2C11&language=english&go=Search .